# how to set input text onscreen swing keyboard to system caret?

Tags: java, swing

i want to write any text or key from swing onscreen keyboard to any caret location like browser notepad office word. i get some example layout, but dont know how to  work to system caret. please teach me how it work.

this example code

```
public class keyboard extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    keyboard frame = new keyboard();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public keyboard() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) { 
            createButton(Integer.toString(i));
            }
        pack();

    }
    private void createButton(String label)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton(label);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        contentPane.add(btn);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: You can try to use `java.awt.Robot` to post native events. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/robot-class-java-awt/) is an example. But you can get some problems with the focus management, because the key events goes posted to the active frame. So when your onscreen keyboard posts an event, this event goes to your app and not to another program. Probably you can avoid this problem by calling the method `setFocusableWindowState(false)` on your frame.

Comment: thanks sir, i will try and learn it. :D